# What happens a perl hash when I surround it in curly braces?

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I am working a trying to understand how this one perl module works, it is called XML::Smart. Most of it was easy to figure out except for one thing that is not so much related to the module.

What I want to do is copy a hash from my script into the XML::Smart module for proccessing. After a little bit of "banning" on it I managed to make it do what I wanted. The problem is I don't what exactly I did. If someone could give a clue of why this works what it means in english that would be great.

I saw something like this when I was messing around with rolling my own modules in that meaning it had something to do with making a class, not sure if that is what it was called or it has anything similar.

Here is my code;

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Smart;

my $xml_obj = XML::Smart->new();

my %config_file = (
    "server01" => {
        "connection" => {
            "address" => "10.0.0.4",
            "port" => "22",
        }, "authentication" => {
            "username" => "admin",
            "password" => "password",
        },
    },
);

$xml_obj->{config} = {%config_file};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It creates a reference to a new hash with a (shallow) copy of the old hash.

`{}` is a hashref.

`{ "foo", "bar", "x", "y" }` defines a hashref with a list of keys and values.

If you put a hash inside `{}` it is in list context, so is turned into a list of keys and values.

Comment: @Solignis — No, that would be a reference to the original hash, not a copy of it.

Comment: What I am trying to do is not so much copy (bad choice of words), I want to "reflect the original hash into the $xml_obj->{config}. Make sense?

Comment: Not really; "reflect" is not a defined term. You can do `$xml_obj->{config} = \%config_file;`, but it's not the same. Changing `%config_file` and changing `%{ $xml_obj->{config} }` changes the same hash, so the change will be seen by both. If that's ok, you can use `$xml_obj->{config} = \%config_file;`. If that's not ok, you want `{ %config_file }` or something that creates a deeper copy (such as Storable's `dclone`).

Comment: Yeah the first example you mentioned is what I am looking to do atleast for now. Ok I think I got it, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to assign %config_file to $xml_obj->{config}
You'll want to do something like a hash slice.

@{ $xml_obj->{config} }{ keys %config_file } = values %config_file;